# Jenkins error "No signing certificate"

Tags: ios, jenkins

when i use Jenkins aotoPackage my iOS api, i meet this log:

=== BUILD TARGET goldNews-iOS OF PROJECT goldNews-iOS WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "9R7KL28K3H" with a private key was found.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

** BUILD FAILED **

This problem bothering me for a long time, if someone can provide advice, I would be most grateful。。。

Comment: The Certificate must exist in the build machines default Key Chain.

Comment: i copy the ios development profile in keychain from "login" to "sysytem" item, and solve this problome,thanks for your answer