# Xcode: No signing certificate

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I downloaded an [Xcode project](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2019/02/basicpdfviewer.zip) from [this webpage](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/02/14/pdf-without-adobe-4-building-your-own-pdf-reader-2/), but when I try to build it, I get this error:

```
error: No signing certificate "Mac Development" found: 
No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "QWY4LRW926" with a private key was found. (in target 'BasicPDFViewer')
```

I've tried to match the Signing options in Build Settings to match those in my own projects, but to no avail.

[image]

I presume the problem is because Xocde is trying to find the Team certificate of the project originator on my Mac. I've tried adding my own Apple ID to Xcode's accounts and creating a Mac Development certificate, but that doesn't help either.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617743/jenkins-error-no-signing-certificate) has been asked, but with no answer that is comprehensible, credible or canonical.

Comment: Is the Team Id selected in the project settings your personal team? And what is the target that you are building for?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the Project Settings about Team IDs. If you could tell me where the Team ID settings are, that would be useful. It's for MacOS 10.12, but I've tried earlier.

Comment: Select your project name in the left panel -> Select the first one in the targets list -> select the General tab. In the signing section, you can see the Team. Select your own team and build it.

Comment: I've changed the value of "Development Team" in the screenshot above to the ID I created in Preferences. Still doesn't work with same error. If you could provide an answer with screenshots, that would be great.

Comment: @benwiggy You need to read a tutorial how to make signing certificate from scratch.

Comment: @TheTiger No, I already had the certificate, I just couldn't find where to select it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can see the Team in the signing section, select your own team there it should work.

Comment: Ah! I had the Project selected in a drop down menu, rather than the Target. (Which appears above your inner sidebar, which I don't have.) Now I can access the General tab. The building process now moves on to the next error. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and I found the solution:

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. Go to the "Build Settings" tab.
3. Under the "Signing" section:

   - Set "Code Signing Identity" to "Sign to run locally".
   - Find "Code Signing Style" and change it to "Manual".

Comment: Thanks! this solution works well. It adds `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "-";` in the .pbxproj file.
`

Comment: In newer versions of xcode it won't like the "-" but you can click on the field and remove the "-" to make it completely blank then it may work.